# Single CREATE TABLE as SELECT completed, but no result rows inserted

Tags: google-bigquery

I use python bigquery.Client to run standard query,like:

```
dml_statement= 'CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT 1 as col)' #DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ahead of that
client = bigquery.Client
client.query(dml_statement)
```

However for different create table as select, sometimes I get a blank table created, no row is there.

If I run the SQL string in console instead of python, then the table is created and rows populated without issue!

If I call just 'SELECT *' part without CREATE TABLE AS from Python, it seems working, because I get the message:

```
<google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator object at 0x000000084B053630>
```

In short, for a working 'CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT 1 as col)', I get result in new table. python message would be 2 lines (1st line should be create table successful?):

```
<google.cloud.bigquery.table._EmptyRowIterator object at 0x0000000783855B38> 

<google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator object at 0x000000084B053630>
```

BUT for a mysterious  'CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT 'unlucky' as col)', I just get an empty table, Python message is just 1 line:

```
<google.cloud.bigquery.table._EmptyRowIterator object at 0x0000004277761128>
```

althrough run in console will get table create and populated, if I just call 'SELECT 'unlucky' as col' from python, it seems working too, because I get:

```
<google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator object at 0x000000084B053630>
```

Comment: I think I find out 1 possible cause of the problem, my query condition may have filtered result to 0 records sometimes.. Will post details when I confirm. I remember I also have an issue of client.insert_rows() would finish but new rows not see, let me dig

Comment: It is intermittent issue (I ran the same python script twice, the first time I get a blank table, next time I get a populated table (added a count afterwards)..I will try to switch to upload_file_to_table using a json file instead of insert_rows.

Comment: The workaround would be to write to GCP therefore avoid streaming

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue but it works well for me. I ran the code:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

dml_statement= """
CREATE TABLE <dataset.table>
 AS SELECT 'unlucky' as col
"""

query_job = client.query(dml_statement)  

query_check = """
SELECT * FROM <dataset.table>
"""

query_job_check = client.query(query_check) 

print("The data:")
for row in query_job_check:
    print("name={}".format( row['col']))
```

We can check that the table is created because the second query returns `name=unlucky`.

I tried other names and structures and the table always gets created fine.
You might need to upgrade the bigquery library version.
For your reference, I used `google-cloud-bigquery==1.17.1` and Python `3.5.2` in the reproduction.